# Isometry in 2D uniquely determined by images at 3 non-colinear points

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, isometry

Prove that if two isometries $f,g$ of the Euclidean 2D space have the same image at 3 non-colinear points $x_i,i=1,2,3$, then they are identical.

Source: Nastasescu C., Nita C., Vraciu C., "Bazele algebrei, vol 1" (Romanian) (translation: Fundamentals of Algebra), page 40.

Comment: This is the raw text of a homework. Have you really worked on the subject ?

Comment: It really is not, I am studying group theory on my own in order to better grasp cryptography. This fact is stated in the book as 'trivial' and is not something crucial for me to know since it is only used to prove some facts about the just introduced 'Dihedral group'. Please see the attached picture (the text says: "De asemenea este clar ca.. o izometrie este unic determinata de imaginile a trei puncte necoliniare" : it is obvious that an isometry is uniquely determined by three non-colinear points: http://imgur.com/a/MvFuwsb

Comment: Also, I did try looking at it a little.  I drew a triangle and its images (still triangle, I considered the isometries as   being translations). It somehow seems obvious the image of a point should be the same since the image has to have the same distance with respect to the images of the initial triangle.. but I wanted a formal proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the following fact:
If $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are in general position (not colinear) and $a,b,c$ are real numbers, then there is at most one point $p$ in the plane so that $d(p,x_1) = a$, $d(p,x_2)=b$, and $d(p,x_3) = c$. *Draw a picture. Circles in the plane with different centers intersect at most twice.*

With this in mind, let $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be given. Then if $a=d(p,x_1)$, $b=d(p,x_2)$, and $c = (p, x_3)$, then
$$d(q,x_1) = a, d(q,x_2)=b, d(q, x_3) = c \Rightarrow q = p$$
Then if $f,g$ are isometries, we have
$$d(f(p), f(x_1)) = a, d(f(p), f(x_2)) = b, d(f(p), f(x_3)) = c$$
$$d(g(p), g(x_1)) = a, d(g(p), g(x_2)) = b, d(g(p), g(x_3)) = c$$
if $f,g$ agree at $x_1,x_2,x_3$, then
$$d(g(p), f(x_1)) = a, d(g(p), f(x_2)) = b, d(g(p), f(x_3)) = c$$
Which implies that $f(p) = g(p)$.

Comment: Thank you! :) It's nice to know my intuition that the images through the isometrirs having same distance to the  images of x1,x2,x3 means they are identical is correct. I was unable to formalize it like you did, though. Awesome!